# How can I find unused step definitions in my test suite?

Tags: python, python-behave

When I run my test suite, the default output of `behave` shows where the steps come from, which is all fine and dandy, except that using this output to find the step definitions that are not *used* would require me to *manually* mark off the steps that are used in order to discover those that aren't.

Can `behave` be invoked in a way that makes it automatically report the step definitions that are not used in the test suite?

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in way, though it is not well documented. In the list of [formatters](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/formatters.html#formatters), there is a formatter named `steps.usage`, which is described as:

> Shows how step definitions are used by steps (in feature files).

This description does not make it explicit, but this formatter not only reports how feature files use the steps but *also* reports unused steps. If there are unused steps in the suite, the output will contain something like:

```
UNUSED STEP DEFINITIONS[8]:
  @then('something')             # features/steps/something.py:1
  @given('some condition')       # features/steps/something.py:12
  [...]
```

The number in square brackets is the number of undefined step definitions found. Then each undefined step is listed, one per line. The line starts with the `@then`/`@given`/etc. decorator that was used to define the step. Then there is a `#` character after which the file and line number of the step definition is given.

You use it like this:

```
behave -f steps.usage --dry-run
```

**Important caveat**: this reporter performs a static analysis of the feature files. This means that if at execution time your steps execute other steps, then the steps that would be run in this way won't be seen as "used" by the formatter, unless they are *also* directly used in a feature file. This may result in the formatter incorrectly reporting some steps as unused. (This happened to me on the very first run I tried.) For instance, the following definition calls two steps at execution time:

```
@when(u"the user does something")
def step_impl(context):
    context.execute_steps(u"""
    When the user does something else
    Then something special happens
    """)
```

The fact that these two steps are used through `context.execute_steps` will *not* be detected by `steps.usage`, and so these steps will be deemed unused unless they *also* appear in verbatim in a feature file.

Note that you can run the formatter without `--dry-run` and in this case, it will really run your suite and produce a report at the end. However, doing this does not fix the issue I've just mentioned. I've tried it, hoping that it would mark as used those steps of mine that are only used through `context.execute_steps`, but it did not work.